# Not In operator in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am pretty new to Angular and I am writing a simple if statement to check if my property isn't one 10 things. Is there a Not In or filter from enums or from a list?

```
public type: string;
if(type === '1' || type === '2' || type === '3') || type === '4'){
// do something
} else {
//do something else
}
```

I am looking for something simple if we can use like

```
if(type not in (1,2,3))
```

What is the best way to check the scenario like this against the string?

Answer (score 3):

```
!['1', '2', '3', '4'].some(val => val === type);
```

or

```
!['1', '2', '3', '4'].includes(type);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.includes()` for the same. The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

[Ref - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
if(['1','2','3','4'].includes(type)) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).